# Groovy, XmlParser, addNode, inserting a array of elements

Tags: arrays, xml, groovy

I have a loop below to create an array of variables on my XML. The issue is that for the first time it is running, it is including all my rows at the first occurrence in my output array.
Any comments are welcome. 
Many thanks!

```
pqpwp*.appendNode('PostalAcc', values[0])
pqpwp*.appendNode('CloseAmt', values[1])
pqpwp*.appendNode('Rates',)
def rates = ltrData.PqPwp.Rates
def values = ["Under 0          0.10%   0.08%      0.10%","Under 1          0.10%   0.08%      0.10%","Under 2          0.10%   0.08%      0.10%","Under 3          0.10%   0.08%      0.10%"]

for (int i = 2; i<10; i++)
{
    if (values[i])
    {
        rates*.appendNode('Rate',)
        def rate = ltrData.PqPwp.Rates.Rate
        rate*.appendNode('Column1', values[i].substring(0,14))
        rate*.appendNode('Column2', values[i].substring(15,23))
        rate*.appendNode('Column3', values[i].substring(24,31))
        rate*.appendNode('Column4', values[i].substring(32,42))
    }
}
```

**actual xml output**

```
      <ltrData>
        <PqPwp>
          <PostalAcc>910060121</PostalAcc>
          <CloseAmt>514.17</CloseAmt>
          <Rates>
            <Rate>
              <Column1>Under �1      2</Column1>
              <Column2>   0.10%</Column2>
              <Column3>  0.08%</Column3>
              <Column4>     0.10%</Column4>
              <Column1>�1 plus       3</Column1>
              <Column2>   1.39%</Column2>
              <Column3>  1.11%</Column3>
              <Column4>     1.40%</Column4>
            </Rate>
            <Rate>
              <Column1>�1 plus       3</Column1>
              <Column2>   1.39%</Column2>
              <Column3>  1.11%</Column3>
              <Column4>     1.40%</Column4>
            </Rate>
          </Rates>
```

xml output desired

```
      <ltrData>
        <PqPwp>
          <PostalAcc>910060121</PostalAcc>
          <CloseAmt>514.17</CloseAmt>
          <Rates>
            <Rate>
              <Column1>Under �1      2</Column1>
              <Column2>   0.10%</Column2>
              <Column3>  0.08%</Column3>
              <Column4>     0.10%</Column4>
            </Rate>
            <Rate>
              <Column1>�1 plus       3</Column1>
              <Column2>   1.39%</Column2>
              <Column3>  1.11%</Column3>
              <Column4>     1.40%</Column4>
            </Rate>
          </Rates>
```

Comment: Is your source data also an xml?

Comment: Hi @Rao thanks for replay. Yes, the input is xml as well. I've just included the [values] array there.

Comment: Would you mind showing nearistic sample (to original xml if not like to show) input and output xmls?

Comment: Hi, below the input XML sample.
<prnReq>
    <ltrPrnReqs>
        <ltrPrnReq>
            <ltrData>910060121;514.17;Under 1          0.10%   0.08%      0.10%;1 plus           1.39%   1.11%      1.40%;;;;;;;;;</ltrData>
        </ltrPrnReq>
    </ltrPrnReqs>
</prnReq>

Position from 2 to 10, each of them is an array of 4 positions each (substrings found in the code). 
Many thanks @Rao!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fixed code is below, hope someone else needs it :)

```
        if (values[i] != "")
            {
            def rate =  rates*.appendNode('Rate')
            rate*.appendNode('Column1',values[i].substring(0,14))
            rate*.appendNode('Column2', values[i].substring(15,23))
            rate*.appendNode('Column3', values[i].substring(24,31))
            rate*.appendNode('Column4', values[i].substring(32,42))
            }    
        }
```